# How to create a latitude bounds with a custom resolution using android maps

Tags: java, android

I'm using a `LatLngBounds.Builder` class to create a zoom level based on two locations which works fine, but I need to create a bound with a half of the screen because I'm using a Bottom Sheet with the layout.

This is the method that draws the `Polyline` and set the bounds between these two locations :

> Update!

I open the Bottom first!

```
private void openBottom(){
    if(latLngs != null){
        if(bottomSheetBehavior.getState() != BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED){
            bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
        }
        drawnNewRoute();
    }
}
```

And then, Draw wth the bounds :

```
private void drawnNewRoute() {
    if(polyline == null){

            po = new PolylineOptions();
            for(int i = 0, tam = latLngs.size(); i < tam; i++){
                po.add(latLngs.get(i));
            }
            String data = new Gson().toJson(latLngs);

            po.color(Color.BLACK).width(10);
            polyline = mMap.addPolyline(po);

            ArrayList<LatLng> latlang = new ArrayList<>();
            latlang.add(latLngs.get(0));
            latlang.add(latLngs.get(latLngs.size() -1));

            mMarkerNewPosition = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(finalLocaltion).title(finalLocationName));
            mMarkerNewPosition.showInfoWindow();

            location_display_incl.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            stopLocation();
            InitialAddressTxt.setText(InitialAddress);
            double finalLat = latLngs.get(latLngs.size() -1).latitude;
            double finalLong = latLngs.get(latLngs.size() -1).longitude;

            try {
                ADRS = getAddress(finalLat,finalLong);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            FinalAddressTxt.setText(finalLocationName);
            String finalComp = ADRS.getLocality() + "," + address.getAdminArea();
            FinalComplement.setText(finalComp);
            zoomToCoverAllMarkersInMap(latlang);
    }
    else{
        polyline.setPoints(latLngs);
    }
}
```

That is the result :

[image]

And this is how I need it

:[image]

The Bottom Sheet XML :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
    android:id="@+id/bottomSheet"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp">
```

Comment: Is you bottom white area is fixed?

Comment: yeah, 300, I'll update

Comment: Okey than it is possible if it is change after the map loading like visible gone than map gone massed up.I will post the answer.

Comment: please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution for your problem.

Declare Arraylist of LatLng.

```
ArrayList<LatLng> latlang;
```

Now initialize the arraylist.

```
latlang = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
```

Now, add fromPostion and toPosition in arraylist. Before adding Declare fromPosition and toPosition object globally so we can use it anytime.

```
LatLng fromPosition;
LatLng toPosition;
```

Now initialize these two object and add your fromLocationLatitude,fromLocationLongitude and toLocationLatitude,toLocationLongitude.

```
fromPosition = new LatLng(fromLocationLatitude, fromLocationLongitude);
toPosition = new LatLng(toLocationLatitude, toLocationLongitude);

latlang.add(fromPosition);
latlang.add(toPosition);
```

After adding both point into array list just pass the arraylist to zoomToCoverAllMarkersInMap() this function and its done.

```
private void zoomToCoverAllMarkersInMap(ArrayList<LatLng> latLngList)
{
    LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();

    for (LatLng marker : latLngList)
    {
        builder.include(marker);
    }

    LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
    int padding = 60;
    final CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);

    googleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition arg0) {
            googleMap.moveCamera(cu);
            googleMap.animateCamera(cu);
            googleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(null);
        }
    });
}
```

Note: setOnCameraChangeListener is deprecated but it still working on 7.0 so no issue with that.

Comment: Doesn't work, the code is almost the same thing but with the deprecated `setOnCameraChangeListener`

Comment: First Expand your Bottomsheet and then try to apply this code.If you set this before expand sheet it will never work.